# How can I get second (third, etc.) line indentation to match first line in a list with custom numbering using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, text-indent

I'm new to HTML, CSS and JavaScript, so this may be a very basic problem, however, I haven't been able to find a solution by searching. Most solutions I've found deal with automatically numbered lists, or un-ordered lists.

I'm using Javascript to populate a list on a webpage from a JSON document. The output HTML list looks like this:

```
<article>
    <div>
        <ul class='foo'><li class='num'>1.</li><li class='txt'>bar</li></ul>
        <ul class='foo'><li class='num'>2.</li><li class='txt'>foo</li></ul>
        <ul class='foo'><li class='num'>2a.</li><li class='txt'>very long test here so that it moves to a new line on the webpage</li></ul>
        <ul class='foo'><li class='num'>5.</li><li class='txt'>bar</li></ul>
        <ul class='foo'><li class='num'>6.</li><li class='txt'>foo</li></ul>
    </div>
</article>
```

I then use CSS to style these to look like a single list:

```
.foo li{
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

This shows the generated numbers with the text to the right, however, if the text is long, like in the third ul in the example above, it loses all indentation when it moves down to a new line. Also, if one number is longer than another, the text to the right of it is indented by the same amount extra, but I'd like to have each line of text start in line with the text above and below it.

I've tried floating each list left and right, but that wrecked the formatting I had on the page. I'm sure there's some simple way to overcome this, but any search I've made has been related to automatically generated numbers for ol objects.

How do I keep my own list numbering, but control the consistency of indentation over multiple lines?

Comment: Text-indent? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent

Comment: Some nice answers, I'm wondering why you're using `<ul>` / `<li>` in the first place though? Why not output a `<table>` instead?

Comment: I'm using <ul>/<li> because, as I mentioned, I'm new to HTML and CSS, and I found that it got closest to what I wanted to do. I didn't know any better way.

Comment: Ok, but you should really use a table then. Also, just for reference, here's one way to do this without table stuff: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/bxhgsa2k/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could render your list as a table:

```
ul.foo {
     display: table;
}
ul.foo > li {
    display: table-cell;
}
ul.foo > li.num {
    min-width: 40px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xbsp30kd/1/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to prevent this is to simply give the list element `display: table-cell`:

```css
.foo li {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div>
    <ul class='foo'>
      <li class='num'>1.</li>
      <li class='txt'>bar</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='foo'>
      <li class='num'>2.</li>
      <li class='txt'>foo</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='foo'>
      <li class='num'>2a.</li>
      <li class='txt'>very long test here so that it moves to a new line on the webpage</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='foo'>
      <li class='num'>5.</li>
      <li class='txt'>bar</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='foo'>
      <li class='num'>6.</li>
      <li class='txt'>foo</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</article>
```

Alternatively, you could make use of `display: flex` on the parent and `display: inline-flex` on the list element:

```css
.foo {
  display: flex;
}

.foo li {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div>
    <ul class='foo'>
      <li class='num'>1.</li>
      <li class='txt'>bar</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='foo'>
      <li class='num'>2.</li>
      <li class='txt'>foo</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='foo'>
      <li class='num'>2a.</li>
      <li class='txt'>very long test here so that it moves to a new line on the webpage</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='foo'>
      <li class='num'>5.</li>
      <li class='txt'>bar</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='foo'>
      <li class='num'>6.</li>
      <li class='txt'>foo</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</article>
```

If you want to get the text 'fully' in line, you'll want to give `margin-left: -8px` to the element that has the additional letter in the numbering:

```css
.foo {
  display: flex;
}

.foo li {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.foo .long {
  margin-left: -8px;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div>
    <ul class='foo'>
      <li class='num'>1.</li>
      <li class='txt'>bar</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='foo'>
      <li class='num'>2.</li>
      <li class='txt'>foo</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='foo'>
      <li class='num'>2a.</li>
      <li class='txt long'>very long test here so that it moves to a new line on the webpage</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='foo'>
      <li class='num'>5.</li>
      <li class='txt'>bar</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='foo'>
      <li class='num'>6.</li>
      <li class='txt'>foo</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</article>
```

Having said all that, the **'best'** way to handle this would be to only use one `<ul>` and make use of `list-style-type: decimal`. This way the indentation lines up, and your numbering is handled for you automatically:

```css
.foo li {
  list-style-type: decimal;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div>
    <ul class='foo'>
      <li>bar</li>
      <li>foo</li>
      <li>very long test here so that it moves to a new line on the webpage</li>
      <li>bar</li>
      <li>foo</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</article>
```

This can even be extended to have sub-lists to cover the Roman lettering, offset with a negative `margin-left`:

```css
.foo li {
  list-style-type: decimal;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.foo li ul li {
  list-style-type: lower-alpha;
  margin-left: -40px;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div>
    <ul class='foo'>
      <li>bar</li>
      <li>foo</li>
      <li>foo
        <ul>
          <li>very long test here so that it moves to a new line on the webpage</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>bar</li>
      <li>foo</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

ul tag should be used only once 
it should be something like this

```
    <ul>
    <li>Items</li>
    <li>Items</li>
    <li>Items</li>
    </ul>
```

you kept on repeating your ul tags and for the custom indexing, you could use span tags instead of using another li tag